# How do I call EDT in a game loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, event-dispatch-thread

I did what someone told me to do with my game loop, adding swing timer etc (except overriding paintComponent as it doesn't apply in this situation), but my game loop refuses to call the Event Dispatching Thread. Because of this, the JFrame does not close and keyboard input is obsele. Can I call EDT manually or is there something I am missing?

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JPanel panel;
public static int screenX = 500;
public static int screenY = 500;
private int w = 0, h = 0;
public Window(){
    super("FileTyper");
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    super.setSize(506,533);
    super.setResizable(false);
    panel = new JPanel();
    super.getContentPane().add(panel);
    super.setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

    super.setVisible(true);
}
public void update(){
    w++;h++;
    if(w>500){
        w = 0;
        h = 0;
    }
}
public void render(Graphics2D g){
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, w, h);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_F9:
        panel.getGraphics().setColor(Color.green);
        panel.getGraphics().drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_F10:
        break;
    }

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

}
```

}

```
 public class Boxy {
public Window window;
boolean running = true;
private BufferedImage offscreen;

public static void main (String args[]){
//      Boxy box = new Boxy();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            begin();

        }
    });
}
public Boxy(){
    //initialize variables

}
public void gameLoop(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            init();
            while(running){
                update();
                render();
                delay();
            }
        }
    });

}
public void runGameLoop()
   {
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            gameLoop();
        }    
    });
    timer.start();
   }
private void init(){
    window = new Window();
    offscreen = new BufferedImage(Window.screenX,Window.screenY,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
}
private void update(){
    window.update();
}
private void render(){
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) offscreen.getGraphics();
    window.render(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) window.panel.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,null);

}
private void delay(){
    try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {System.out.println("ERROR: Delay compromised");}
}
public static void begin(){
        Boxy box = new Boxy();
        box.runGameLoop();
}
```

}

Comment: You are blocking the EDT by calling `Thread.sleep`. There are multiple posts here on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `javax.swing.Timer` guarantees that the `actionPerformed` method of the assigned `ActionListener` is called within the context of the EDT
2. Running the infinite loop within the EDT is now blocking it, preventing from ever updating the UI.

Your `runGameLoop` should look more like...

```
public void runGameLoop()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            update();
            render();
        }    
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Before implementing any suggestions, its recommended to try and understand what those recommendations are trying to acheive...

Have a read through

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For more details.

Comment: But isn't it possible to still call EDT with an infinite loop? A demo program I downloaded did that, although I have no idea why

Comment: @Killam: `"But isn't it possible to still call EDT with an infinite loop?"` -- that's the whole reason to use the Swing Timer -- to have a loop that doesn't lock the EDT. An infinite loop otherwise will lock whatever thread it is called in, EDT or otherwise. This has nothing to do with Swing but all to do with basic Java. 1+

Comment: No, it's not, ever possible to use an infinite within the context of the EDT.  It will stop the EDT from processing new events, including repaint events.  I bet your example used a background thread of some kind

Comment: Unless you have some reason to control the timing between the updates, a Swing `Timer` is an excellent class for this purpose.